# Where does system.out.println in tomcat under windows gets written?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

I am using a third party library (cannot modify it) that uses for logging system.out.println statements. The output shows fine in the console but I am not able to retrieve those information in the catalina[...].log file?

Is it possible to send those to log4j?

Comment: Why exactly did you tag `log4j`? How exactly is this question related to Log4j?

Comment: I am hoping to be able to send those to log4j

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.out.println()` prints out to stdout. Therefore, if you want to see these statements in a log file, you can just redirect stdout where you want it in the Tomcat startup script.

Comment: No need to guess, `tomcat` is just tagged as such.

Comment: do you have a link that explains how to do that configuration?

Comment: @Stainedart you have to customize your starter script.

Comment: "Tomcat startup script" and "starter script" are vague -- what are you talking about?

Comment: here is how to redirect stdout,

Edit conf/logging.properties and change this line

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

to

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

Then it will only log to catalina.<date>.log or tomcat8-stdout.<date>.log.
"answerd by sourcedelica from serverfault.com"

Answer (score 15):

When running Tomcat on unixes, the console output is usually redirected to the file named **catalina.out**. The name is configurable using an environment variable. (See the startup scripts).

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Console

Answer (score 3):

You can find those logs also in cat /var/log/messages

if you try

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep server
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a JSP then you need to add

```
 <%@ page isThreadSafe="false"  %>
```

Then all of your System.out.printlns will start showing up in the catalina.out file.

If you start tomcat with Catalina.sh run from a command line you will see the prints in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it inside `TOMCAT_HOME/logs/stdout_20130104.txt` (the file name may change but the log files are usually in the folder `TOMCAT_HOME/logs/`.

And for me all the sysouts that I have in my code are written in such a file.

Comment: These files don't exist for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Fedora 29 apache-tomcat-8.5.39), it was found inside **catalina.out** file located inside **logs** folder.