# Tomcat 8 log file not showing System.out.Println data

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat8

I have ubuntu VM in this VM i installed Tomcat 8 and deploy Java Web Application, in this Application I use the following code

`System.out.println("Testing text");`

But when i check my tomcat log via `/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.2016-05-20.log`
file there is nothing print like "Testing text".
But my application is running successfully there is no error.

my `/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties` file content

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I would try java.util.logging; also, maybe my question is childish, but have to ask: do you print out on the server side of your app?

Comment: What about the file [catalina.out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25583863/108341)?

Comment: @Michaël cataline.out file contains only the following data : "/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 401: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 401: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory"

Comment: @user3441151 Have you open every file in your logs folder?

Comment: @Michaël yes but no file contain the sysout text.

Comment: Does this help: [How to log stdout output in Tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740257/how-to-log-stdout-output-in-tomcat)

Comment: @Michaël when i deploy any application then log will be generated on /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.2016-05-20.log file but when i execute my application then nothing will change on this file.

Comment: @Michaël i just update my logging.properties file content, please check it if is there any issue.

Comment: @Nicholas i just update my logging.properties file content, please check it.

Comment: Why don't you use a logging framework instead of sysout?

Comment: @meskobalazs i don't know about logging framework.

Comment: @meskobalazs how can i use it.