# Capture System.out.println in log file on Tomcat 9?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

How do I get Tomcat 9 to log output from System.out.println to some log file where I can see it?

My application uses java.util.logging.Logger for logging and I get those messages in my catalina.out file.

The problem is that a 3rd party package I am using is logging output that I need with System.out.println, and I'm not getting that output. I don't have the source code to this package so I can't update it to use Logger.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158131/where-does-system-out-println-in-tomcat-under-windows-gets-written) answer your question?

Comment: You can use [sysout-over-slf4j](https://projects.lidalia.org.uk/sysout-over-slf4j) ("*a work-around for poorly behaving third party modules*") to get the logging into SLF4J, which can these route it to your logging impl. of choice. You should really shout at whoever wrote that 3rd party code though. If they're making relatively basic mistakes like that, it doesn't give me much confidence the rest of their code will work as intended.